# Restricting website access by country

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, geolocation, amazon-route53

I am hosting my website using AWS.

The website is on 2 ec2 instances, with a load balancer (ELB) balancing traffic between them.

Currently, I am using my DNS (Route 53) to restrict the access to the website by using Route 53's geolocation routing: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo

(The geolocation restriction is just to limit the initial release of my website. It is not for security reasons. Meaning the restriction just needs to work for the general public)

This worries me a little because my load balancer is still exposed to access from everywhere. So I am concerned that my load balancer will get indexed by google or something and then people outside of my region will be able to access the site.

Are there any fixes for this? Am I restricting access by location the wrong way? Is there a way perhaps to specify in the ELB's security group that it only receive inbound traffic from my DNS (of course then I would also have to specify that inbound traffic from edge locations be allowed as well for my static content but this is not a problem)?

Note: There is an option when selecting inbound rules for a security group, under "type" to select "DNS(UDP)" or "DNS(TCP)". I tried adding two rules for both DNS types (and IP Address="anywhere") for my ELB but this did not limit access to the ELB to be solely through my DNS.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are having an initial limited release of the website, why not make the decision at the application layer and show a 'coming soon' page to those that you don't want to give access to. Otherwise you might prevent possible customers visiting your site once it is live in their region

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input. I am not sure how to implement this at the application level (specifically, associating a country with an ip address). There's this website which does this: http://ipinfo.io/. but they charge for anything over 1000 requests...Your suggestion is one possible approach but I would trust AWS with associating an IP address to a region more than some third party like the one I just listed. Would you agree? Or is associating an IP address with a location a straightforward procedure.

Answer (score 8):

The simple solution, here, is found in CloudFront.  Two solutions, actually:

CloudFront can use its GeoIP database to do the blocking for you...

> When a user requests your content, CloudFront typically serves the requested content regardless of where the user is located. If you need to prevent users in specific countries from accessing your content, you can use the CloudFront geo restriction feature[...]
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html

You can configure CloudFront with which countries are allowed, or which are denied.  You can also configure static pages, stored in S3, which are displayed to denied users.  (You can also configure static custom error pages for other CloudFront errors that might occur, and store those pages in S3 as well, where CloudFront will fetch them if it ever needs them).

**...or...**

CloudFront can pass the location information back to your server using the `CloudFront-Viewer-Country:` header, and your application code, based on the contents accompanying that header, can do the blocking.  The incoming request looks something like this (some headers munged or removed for clarity):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 3fkkTxKhNxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==
Via: 1.1 cb76b079000000000000000000000000.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
CloudFront-Viewer-Country: US
CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto: https
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

CloudFront caches the responses against *the combination of* the requested page and the viewer's country, and any other whitelisted headers, so it will correctly cache your denied responses as well as your allowed responses, independently.

Here's more about how you enable the `CloudFront-Viewer-Country:` header:

> If you want CloudFront to cache different versions of your objects based on the country that the request came from, configure CloudFront to forward the CloudFront-Viewer-Country header to your origin. CloudFront automatically converts the IP address that the request came from into a two-letter country code.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-location

Or, of course, you can enable both features, letting CloudFront do the blocking, while still giving your app a heads-up on the country codes for the locations that were allowed through.

---

But how do you solve the issue with the fact that your load balancer is still open to the world?

CloudFront has recently solved this one, too, with Custom Origin Headers.  These are secret custom headers sent to your origin server, by CloudFront, with each request.

> You can identify the requests that are forwarded to your custom origin by CloudFront. This is useful if you want to know whether users are bypassing CloudFront[...]
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html

So, let's say you added a custom header to CloudFront:

```
X-Yes-This-Request-Is-Legit: TE9MIHdoYXQgd2VyZSB5b3UgZXhwZWN0aW5nIHRvIHNlZT8=
```

What's all that line noise?  Nothing, really, just a made up secret value that only your server and CloudFront know about.  Configure your web server so that if this header and value are not present in the incoming request, then access is denied -- this is a request that didn't pass through CloudFront.

Don't use the above secret, of course... make up your own.  It's entirely arbitrary.

---

Caveat applicable to **any** GeoIP-restricting strategy: it isn't perfect.  CloudFront [claims 99.8% accuracy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html#georestrictions-cloudfront).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Is there any way to restrict specific pages on my website by region using this method?

Comment: For the second method I suggested, **yes**, because your application would make the blocking decision based on the `CloudFront-Viewer-Country:` header.  For the first method I mentioned, **no**... CloudFront's geo restrictions appear to apply to the entire distribution as a whole.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. The methods you outlined deny access to specific (static) content on my site. I would like to deny access to my entire website (not just static content, especially since the only static content I'm hosting is css and js type files that the use never accesses directly). The first method you outlined can't do this as far as I can tell. I don't think the second method can do it either? Unless you have some suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing about either solution that restricts them to static content.  CloudFront supports static and dynamic content, and with either scenario, your entire web site would run through CloudFront.  Let me know if I can clarify further, but I believe I understood your requirements and that both of these are an excellent fit.

Comment: Yes, then I need some clarification. Looking at the first method:
1) A user requests my website homepage.
2) The page loads and attempts to access my cloudfront url to load (eg) the css for that page.
3) Since the user is in a blacklisted location, the content returned FROM THE REQUEST FOR THE CSS FILE is a "403 - forbidden" error message. Therefore, the page proceeds to load without the css file.
Where in this process can I then restrict access to the page the user is trying to view? Or does this page have to also be served by cloudfront in order for this to happen? (Most my pages are jsps)

Comment: Maybe I need to read a little more about CloudFront? I am not serving my entire site from there.

Comment: Yes, these solutions require the entire site to be served through CloudFront, which now supports dynamic content, `POST` and other standard verbs, can handle different cache/no-cache behaviors, so this is usually a sensible strategy and can result in no net cost increase or even a savings.

Comment: It might be too involved for me to implement this change at the moment. Is there any way to easily restrict access to only me while I test this out? Signed urls seems a bit involved.

Comment: You don't need signed URLs for this. (Where did you get that idea?) Create a new CloudFront distribution, point it to your origin server, and use the default `http://dxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net` address assigned to the distribution, to surf your site and test the restrictions.

Comment: Yes, I didn't like that this link is open to the public. But if it's an obscure domain then it's not a concern? (for things like google indexing, etc.)?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, for testing.  [AWS Web Application Firewall](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/faq/) is an adjunct to CloudFront and allows you to pretty easily allow/deny access to a CloudFront distribution by IP address (and/or other parameters).

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help. At the moment, because I am assuming that implementing this change (serving dynamic content via ClouFront) will result in some unexpected hurdles (for example, I'm curious what happens when requests are forwarded within my server when I'm serving dynamic content through CF, will the request first go back to the edge location and then to the server). I will probably most likely serve dynamic content from CloudFront eventually because it seems like a nice solution (even when I will no longer need georestriction).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot this is a better link specific to cloudfront restricting load balancer access: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/restrict-access-to-load-balancer.html

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to implement geographic IP restrictions, is to use a geographic location database or service API, and implement it at the application level.

For example, for a web site in practically any language, it is very simple to add test at the start of each page request, and compare the client IP against the geo ip database or service, and handle the response from there.

At the application level, it is easier to manage the countries you accept/deny, and log those events, as needed, than at the network level.

IP based geo location data is generally reliable, and there are many sources for this data. While you may trust AWS for many things, I do think that there are many reliable 3rd party sources for geo IP dat, that focus on this data.

- [freegeoip.net](https://freegeoip.net) provides a public HTTP API to search the geolocation of IP addresses. You're allowed up to 10,000 queries per hour.
- [ip2location.com LITE](http://lite.ip2location.com/) is a free IP geolocation database for personal or commercial use.

If your application uses a database, these geo databases are quite easy to import and reference in your app.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I am deciding between your answer and Michael's. One potential drawback of your solution is if I apply something like a filter which checks the country of the user then I think it will significantly lengthen the response time of each request (every country limited page will need to wait for a response from freegeoip.net before proceeding)...However, your solution seems simpler to implement.

Comment: Regarding overhead on each page, if you are using session variables, you can set a session flag when the IP is accepted, with the current IP, and consult it on each request.  If present, and it equals the current IP, the there is no need to request a new IP lookup from the database or API. This will minimize overhead significantly.

Comment: Is there any reason you would be against serving dynamic content via cloudfront and using cloudfront's georestriction?

Comment: This should not be used in production. freegeoip.net is not reliable enough to run in production (the HTTP service).

Answer (score 0):

I have a post explaining in detail how to whitelist / blacklist locations with Route53: https://www.devpanda.me/2017/10/07/DNS-Blacklist-of-locations-countries-using-AWS-Route53/.

In terms of your ELB being exposed to public that shouldn't be a problem since the Host header on any requests to the ELB over port 80 / 443 won't match your domain name, which means for most web servers a 404 will be returned or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way using AWS WAF
You can select - Resource type to associate with web ACL as ELB.
Select your ELB and create conditions like Geo Match, IP Address etcetera.
You can also update anytime if anything changes in future.
Thanks